# Google Cloud build unable to find git path

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

I have a docker file, which is running `npm install`. When i submit this to `gcloud builds submit --tag <tag>`, i get the following error:

```
....
npm ERR! path git
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn git
npm ERR! enoent Error while executing:
npm ERR! enoent undefined ls-remote -h -t ssh://git@github.com/web3-js/WebSocket-Node.git
npm ERR! enoent
npm ERR! enoent
npm ERR! enoent spawn git ENOENT
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent
```

From the error message above, and the results in googling for "undefined ls-remote -h -t ssh://git@github.com", it appears that the issue is that the git path is undefined.

Is there a workaround for this?

---

EDIT:

```
# reference: https://www.docker.com/blog/keep-nodejs-rockin-in-docker/

# Operating System

FROM node:10.16.3-slim

# create app directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package-lock.json ./
COPY package.json ./

RUN npm install --no-optional
# for production: RUN npm ci

COPY . .

#EXPOSE 8080
# Environment variables
ENV mode help


CMD ["sh", "-c", "node src/app.js ${mode}"]
```

I now think this is because i used the `-slim` version of the nodejs docker image (going by the recommendation in the docker blog post). I hadn't realized these images also include other programs like git, etc. that are often needed for nodejs.

Comment: Can you please add the Dockerfile as well to see if everything is ok?

Comment: Your error is caused by npm running an input file as a shell script. Most like you mean to run a script that is running npm. Edit your question and post your project and source/script files.

Comment: thanks - i added the Dockerfile above, with an updated reason i suspect.

Sorry, i'm unable to include the other source/script files since its a private repo.

Comment: If that is indeed the reason, i can just use the non-slim image, `From node:10.16.3`. The bloat is okay for my purposes; we don't need to get into explanations on how to install git :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 things to not mix:

- The git `tag`
- The Cloud Build `tag`

The git `tag` is a value that you put in your repository to get the code at a certain point of time. The `git ls-remote` command is the right one for this. However the tag is empty and the `ls-remote` takes the `ssh://` git url as the tag name.

The [Cloud Build `tag`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/builds/submit#--tag) if the name of your container in the gcr docker hub. it's usually `gcr.io/<project_id>/<name that you want>`

For solving your issue, you have 2 solutions:

- Use `docker build` command. Use the `tag` to name your container, and use an environment variable `-e GIT_TAG=xxx` to use in your Dockerfile to specify the git tag
- Use Cloud Build config file, by default `cloudbuild.yaml` and use the same logic with environment variable in your `Dockerfile`. For passing your `GIT_TAG` to the Cloud Build, use [substitution variables](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/configuring-builds/substitute-variable-values). You can use your own substitution variable which must start by underscore, or use the predefined `TAG_NAME` variable. In both case, you have to specify it when you run your Cloud Build command

Command: `gcloud builds submit --substitutions=TAG_NAME="test"` or `gcloud builds submit --substitutions=_MY_TAG_NAME="test"`

`cloudbuild.yaml` file

```
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  args: ['build', '-t', 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/my-image', '.', '-e', 'GIT_TAG=$_MY_TAG_NAME']

# my-image is pushed to Container Registry
images:
- 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/my-image'
```

You can see that the `docker build` command line and the Cloud Build definition are exactly the same.

By the way you can test your build with docker build locally (or on Cloud Shell) for quicker tests and iteration and then package it in `cloudbuild.yaml` file.

**UPDATE**

With your additional details, you don't have git installed in your base image.
Add this line before your `npm install`

`RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y git`

Comment: thanks @guillaume. I updated the question with the Dockerfile. I don't think it has to do with the git-tag, but with the nodejs slim image i was trying to use. Apologies for not providing adequate info at the outset.

Comment: Apologizes are mine, I didn't go to the end of the git line and I didn't see that it was a generic package. I updated my answer